# How to query multiple instances to see if a service has gone down on one or the other in Prometheus

Tags: prometheus

I have two instances that i want to query and check if the service is down. I am using the absent syntax though it doesn't allow regex so my query is long. I was wondering if there is a cleaner way to do this?

absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="xxx:9182", process="npop3"}) or absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="yyy:9182", process="npop3"}) or
absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="xxx:9182", process="nreplica"}) or absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="yyy:9182", process="nreplica"}) or
absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="xxx:9182", process="nrouter"}) or absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="yyy:9182", process="nrouter"}) or
absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="xxx:9182", process="nsmtp"}) or absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="yyy:9182", process="nsmtp"}) or
absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="xxx:9182", process="nldap"}) or absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="yyy:9182", process="nldap"}) or
absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="xxx:9182", process="nhttp"}) or absent(windows_process_start_time{instance="yyy:9182", process="nhttp"})

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex in your metric `windows_process_start_time`

Something like this would work in your case

```
absent(windows_process_start_time{instance=~"xxx:9182|yyy:9182", process=~"n.*"})
```

Using `=~` instead of `=` will evaluate the string as a regex, and then you can specify your regex in the string.

For more information on PromQL regex look at [PromQL querying](https://prometheus.io/docs/prometheus/latest/querying/basics/#time-series-selectors)

Comment: The problem with this query is that when you use regex with absent it doesn't return the instance name only the value. Makes it problematic for alerting.